# Need advice with a CollectionView scenario

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a CV which displays a bunch of images (obviously). Each image has a button, when viewing in fullscreen, that allows the user to like (save) the image to their profile. There is a user profile button on the bottom of the screen. When the user taps that button, I'm reloading the CV and only showing the images the user has liked/saved. After quick coding, it worked but with one major bug. I'm setting the numberOfItemsInSection = to the number of images in the user's profile (initially, this value is set to the total number of records(images) returned from the cloud). The problem is that it's only showing some of the images that the user has liked and also showing images they haven't liked, but the number of cells being displayed is correct. For example, say there are a total of 50 records, therefore, 50 cells/images. The user has previously liked 10 of them. So tapping the profile button refreshes the CV and now there's only 10 cells. However, the liked images happen to be at indexes 3, 7, 9 and the remaining liked images all reside at index > 9 and therefore are not seen. So all 10 cells are displaying images, but only cells at index 3, 7 and 9 are correct. Obviously, my goal is to have all 10 cells show only the 10 images from the user's profile in this example. I hope that was clearly explained.

So I'm wondering how to accomplish this. My first thought was to try and do some sort of for loop inside of cellForItemAtIndexPath where I would check to see if the image at that index is a liked image and if not proceed to the next index until reaching a liked image before setting the cell's imageview to that image. However, I'm not sure if a for loop inside cellForItemAtIndexPath is really feasible. My next thought was to hide any cell at a given index if it's not a liked image. I played around with this and it sort of worked, but the cells were no longer organized correctly, i.e. a lot of blank spaces and it did not undo itself like it should when tapping the profile button again to show all images.

Can anyone please provide some feedback on the best approach to take with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're changing the number but not filtering the data source to match. Your selection set is a discontiguous selection, so you need to adapt the datasource to properly represent item/section contiguously. How you do that will depend quite a bit on what your original data structure is and how flexibly it would handle internal filtering.

Comment: The datasource is basically an array containing objects with the images and associated data...what you're saying makes sense, but I guess that's the root of my question, how do I filter the data so it matches?

Comment: I got your problem but Some Code Would be helpful... Currently my best guess is that you are updating using updated datasource in `numberOfItemsInSection` but not in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: "how do I filter the data so it matches?" That's the million dollar question. You have lots of ways, including brute-force (actually remove entries from the array when necessary, reload it completely when you need all of them) and almost-brute-force, create a second array of only the liked/saved then use _that_ as the datasource as appropriate, switching back and forth. Both of those would be poor implementations for production code, but they can get you going and you can make it as elegant as desired from there.

Comment: That's funny...the second array with only the liked/saved images was the very first thought I had when I was trying to do this. But I dismissed it almost immediately as not being a good implementation. I HATE duplicating data that already exists and try to avoid it at all costs. After thinking about your comments, I think the best way would probably be to just sort the array when the button is tapped so that all the liked/saved images are at the front of the array. That way all the images at the needed indexes would contain only the correct images. Thanks a lot for the input!

Comment: As an aside, don't forget to define a sort order for the "everything" case to keep images in the same ordering whether you're applying "the filter" or not, lest you have a poor user experience (unexpected changes in position from action to action).

Comment: Yep, I had already thought of that...do you have any such examples you can point me to? I haven't sorted arrays in objective-c before. Doesn't seem as straight forward as how I used to do it in Java. Thank you sir!

Comment: Uncle Google gives many results on "objective-c sort array" ;-) (NOTE: I'm not *just* being a smartass. The approach to sorting will be common in the examples, but the details will vary based on the information you specifically have available to you.)

Comment: Yeah, I had googled it but didn't seem to find any clear enough examples similar to what I'm doing. I'll try again...I was just doing a quick search and glance. Thanks!

Comment: If you wind up having trouble translating something that looks like what you want, that's an opportunity for a new, specific question: "I have this sample code, I have this array, I want it sorted this way. Here's what I've tried, here's how it's failing... help!"